# targeting and understanding CSS child selectors

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to target the class, `.textbox-fill` to change the background colour and text colour for each individual box element. For example `.textbox-fill`'s first-child should be grey. The second-child should be white. The third child I want to adjust the height slight and so on.

I have tried using the `nth-child` selector  `#About-Container .about-inner-content article:nth-child(1n+2) .textbox-fill` nothing seems to work. [Example here](http://portland-design.com/wp/wp-portland/about/)

```
    <article class="col-sm-6 grid-tile">

  <div class="textbox-fill">
  <div class="about-textbox">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>

</div>
 </div>  
  </article>
```

I have encounter this issue in the past and I'm not 100% sure how I resolved it. I have read several articles and posts on this subject. I understand the basics, however something more complex like this I always approached with trial and error method.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about what is your desired result?

Comment: I am trying to change the background colour on the class .textbox-fill. Each textbox-fill class should have a different colour

Comment: `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` only counts elements which share the ***very same*** parent element. So your selector will have to start at the highest level they all have in common, that is `.about-inner-content:nth-child(2n) .textbox-fill { background-color: red; } .about-inner-content:nth-child(2n+1) .textbox-fill { background-color: yellow; }`.

Comment: I think you're slightly misunderstanding my question. Try to inspect the code first then you'll have a better understand of what i am asking

Comment: That might be because you didn't follow the requirements of a minimal, verifiable and complete example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't follow …..

Comment: Okay, go ahead help yourself then.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're getting defensive. I was about to further elaborate on my question. I know how sensitive individuals are on here

Comment: Are you using LESS? `&:nth-child(2)` is not valid in CSS, as far as I know.  Use `:nth-child(2)` instead. @connexo provided the proper syntax.

Comment: using sass. The code i above it an example, it's not the actual code I am using on the page. How no has check the link. I will edit it before ppl have a hissy fit

Comment: No one is going to look through all your front-end code here, I think. Please provide the relevant code in your question to increase your chances on getting the answer. Keep in mind that this is not about being nice/rude, but simply about following Stackoverflow's rules.

Comment: @DmitriyDemir it's not really a case of looking through my it's a case of viewing the page to understand what i am explaining

Comment: @DmitriyDemir I've already had connexo jump to conclusions and go off one when he was completely talking the wrong thing

Comment: @connexo that part was understood before i wrote the question fella. It's not what i am looking for. If you notice on the page I have managed to target block one and two

Comment: So it's the `2n+1` etc stuff you don't understand?

Comment: yes! that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `.textbox-fill` is inside the `article`, it is the `article` you need to start with, as target the `text-fill` using `nth-child` will not work as it can't *see outside its parent*

So do like this instead

```css
article:nth-child(1) .textbox-fill {
  color: red;
}

article:nth-child(2) .textbox-fill {
  color: lime;
}

article:nth-child(3) .textbox-fill {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-sm-6 grid-tile">

  <div class="textbox-fill">
    <div class="about-textbox">
      <h2>Some text</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 grid-tile">

  <div class="textbox-fill">
    <div class="about-textbox">
      <h2>Some text</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 grid-tile">

  <div class="textbox-fill">
    <div class="about-textbox">
      <h2>Some text</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

If we talk about the `.textbox-fill`'s `.about-textbox`'s children, the `h2` and `p`, do like this, where you use the global selector `*` in `*:nth-child`, as the children is of different types

```css
.textbox-fill .about-textbox *:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

.textbox-fill .about-textbox *:nth-child(2) {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-sm-6 grid-tile">

  <div class="textbox-fill">
    
    <div class="about-textbox">
      
      <h2>Some text</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.textbox-fill` with several children, like:

```
div.textbox-fill
  h1#header
  div#firstDiv
  div#secondDiv
  article#someArticle
  div#thirdDiv
```

Now, `.textbox-fill div:first-child` will target nothing, because there isn't any div that is a first child of it's parent (.textbox-fill). Although `.textbox-fill div:first-of-type` will target `div#firstDiv`. `.textbox-fill div:nth-child(2)` will also target `div#firstDiv`. `div#thirdDiv` will be `.textbox-fill div:nth-of-type(3)` or `.textbox-fill div:nth-child(5)` or `.textbox-fill div:last-child` or `.textbox-fill div:last-of-type`.

If you want to target specific `.textbox-fill` located on site, but with different parents, like:

```
div.something
  div.textbox-fill
[...]
article#other
  div.textbox-fill
```

You cannot target it using `nth-child` nor `nth-of-type`. You will need to find another way based on your site tree.